# When we touch an animal it is "pet" or "pat"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

When we touch an animal it is "pet" or "pat"?
Should we say "Can I pet" or "Can I pat him" (a dog)?

Comment: I often pat my cat when I am petting him. :-)

Comment: both but "pet" is more common.

Comment: Patting is one way of petting. Kissing, rubbing etc also is petting

Comment: In Australian English, we say "pat". In American English, "pet" is most common. In British English, "stroke" is most common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When one approaches a stranger's animal, it is polite (and wise) to ask,

> *May I pet your dog?* or, *May I pet him?* If you do not know the animal's gender, it might be preferable to say *your dog* to *it*, although *it* is perfectly grammatical. One might do this as a way of respecting strong feelings one may have for a pet.

As for "pet" or "pat", both are correct. *Pat* connotes a light, quick stroke with the hand.

> She gave him a friendly pat on the arm.

To *pet* an animal is to stroke or caress gently; **pat**; to touch or stroke in an affectionate or loving manner.

> When I pet my cat, I feel very calm.

Comment: I think of *pat* as having more motion perpendicular to the "patted" surface, whereas *pet* has more motion parallel to the "petted" surface.

Comment: @Jim - that is my mental image as well.

Comment: @Jim - At the risk of a "Me, too" comment I think its significant to emphasize the direction of motion as the difference between pet and pat.